# Error while selecting a particular element froma Array in spark sq

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a Json using spark sql and print the values

Actually I want to select only the 0th element of the array

when I try to select the complete array,it works, but when I try to select 0th element from array then it fails

```
val events = sc.parallelize("""{"toid":"osgb4000000031043205","point":[508180.748,195333.973],"index":1}""" :: Nil)

 val schema = new StructType().add("toid",StringType,true).add("point",DataTypes.createArrayType(DoubleType,true),true).add("index",StringType,true)

val df = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(events)

df.show 

 +--------------------+--------------------+-----+
 |                toid|               point|index|
 +--------------------+--------------------+-----+
 |osgb4000000031043205|[508180.748, 1953...|    1|
 +--------------------+--------------------+-----+


scala> df.select("point")[0].show
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
   df.select("point")[0].show
                      ^

scala> df.select("point")(0).show
<console>:48: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: String
          df.select("point")(0).show
```

Could someone help me on this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing the following by taking the 0th element inside the `select` function and not outside the `select` function.

```
df.select($"point"(0)).show
```

You can even create column name using alias as

```
df.select($"point"(0).as("firstValue")).show
```

I hope the answer is helpful